# Where can I learn to create my own theme?

Tags: themes, theme-development

I want to learn how to create a theme for WordPress.

Where can I find information and resources on how to do it?

Comment: You may want to check the tutorials that are compatible with the new Twenty Ten theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many different ways to learn to create your own theme.

1. First, there's the ["official" WordPress Codex on Developing Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), but I'd say that it is more of a reference than a tutorial.
2. Another approach and one I like a lot is to read some of the better tutorials about WordPress Theming on the various blogs around the web. Here are some reasonably good ones, in no particular order:

   - "[How to Build a Custom WordPress Theme from Scratch](http://www.blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-build-a-custom-wordpress-theme-from-scratch)" on SpoonGraphics.co.uk (Feb 2010)
   - "[How To Create a WordPress Theme: The Ultimate WordPress Theme Tutorial](http://themeshaper.com/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/)" on Themeshaper.com (Jun 2009)
   - "[Building Custom WordPress Theme](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/building-custom-wordpress-theme/)" on WebDesignerWall.com (Nov 2008)
3. Yet another option is to check out some of the videos/screencasts on the subject such as this series of videos/screenacasts which I've found to be one of the better ones:

   - WordPress Theme Tutorial by andrewanimation/AMPtutorials on YouTube:

     - [Part 1 - Setup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2kl3kEfni4)
     - [Part 2 - Homepage and Functions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xt7cGBr9of0)
     - [Part 3 - Single Post Template](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJBUYsRtJ80)
     - [Part 4 - Custom Comment Display](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSKZZEB7Iqs)
     - [Part 5a - Customizing Your Comment List](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLEocShvqqg)
     - [Part 5b - Customizing Your Comment List](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWeO_xSEz-Q)
     - [Part 6 - Additional Pages](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRI9NI37ZWg)
     - [Part 7a - Dynamic Sidebars](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmrVU8PTeJk)
     - [Part 7b - Multiple Sidebars](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_CqyEDDZWw)
     - [Part 8a - Adding a Theme Options Page](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAkdS3qMCzs)
     - [Part 8b - Adding a Theme Options Page](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFtURSgBr40)

     .
4. Then of course there are the books you can get, if you must go this route (be sure to hunt for the used ones on Amazon; they are often much cheaper than new):

   - [Smashing WordPress: Beyond the Blog](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470684151)
   - [Build Your Own Wicked Wordpress Themes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980455294)
   - [Rockstar WordPress Designer](http://rockablepress.com/books/rockstar-wordpress-designer/)
   - [WordPress Theme Design: A complete guide to creating professional WordPress themes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1847193099)
   - [WordPress 2.8 Themes Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1847198449)
   - [WordPress 2.8 Theme Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849510083)

   .
5. Lastly you can hang out here and ask questions and/or any of these other places where there are always WordPress-istas willing to help:

   - [**WordPress Group on LinkedIn**](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=154024) - for WordPress users, developers, and consultants, to connect, and to share ideas, questions, and contacts.
   - [**WP Tavern Forum**](http://www.wptavern.com/forum/) - forum with various sections for discussion including topics such as general WordPress, business, plugins and hacks, resources and tutorials, themes and templates, and troubleshooting.
   - [**WP Garage**](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/wpgarage/) - mailing list at Yahoo which provides advice and answers to questions relating to WordPress.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

There are many different resources and tutorials on creating your own theme, particularly in series which cover starting out with WP to creating a themes options panel. A few good resources:

- [WP Codex - Theme Developement](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
- [Nettuts+/ThemeForest - WordPress for Designers](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/who-needs-university-the-best-nettuts-screencast-training-courses/) (you have to scroll down to no. 9 to see the list of episodes for WP)
- [CSS-Tricks - Designing for WordPress](http://css-tricks.com/designing-for-wordpress-complete-series-downloads/)

[This](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/top-50-wordpress-tutorials/) Nettuts+ article also contains a selection of great links to WP theme tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

The official place to start would be:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
Another good article with various resources from smashing magazine is [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/29/ultimate-guide-to-using-wordpress-for-a-portfolio/)

Answer (score 2):

While I've worked through some of the Wordpress Codex tutorials and reference material, the best resource I've found so far is a book that I can heartily recommend:

[Smashing Wordpress: Beyond the Blog (Amazon link)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470684151).

It walks you through which files to amend, how to properly ('safely') change the xhtml, php, css to effect changes throughout. On-line tutorials and references are somewhat easier to get hold of, but I enjoy reading off-line and remember more from hard-copy for whatever reason. Bear in mind, though, that this is the only Wordpress book I've bought recently, so my sample size is ridiculously small.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start is the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).  It has several tutorials that walk you through templating, building the loop, and customizing your theme to do whatever you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a great resource for starting out with theme development: http://themeshaper.com/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very clean tutorial step by step on how to create a theme:

[Spoongraphics](http://www.blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-build-a-custom-wordpress-theme-from-scratch)

Answer (score 0):

A nice Tutorial I got was [Ian Stewart](http://themeshaper.com/author/superuser/)'s Theme Development Tutorial:

> [**WordPress Theme Templates : Templates Tutorial** — ThemeShaper.com](http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/)